# R shiny ReactiveFileReader doesn't read the data on first load

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have a basic shiny webpage where I need to automatically update data so I used reactiveFileReader, but it doesn't work for me when I open the page for the first time. Here is the ui piece of the code I wrote:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Some Heading"),
      tabsetPanel(
       tabpanel("TabA", fluid = TRUE,
                  sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput('StFX'),
                    actionButton("UpdateFX", "UpdateView")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    tableOutput("viewFX")
               ),
       tabpanel("TabB", fluid = TRUE,
                  sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput('StCD'),
                    actionButton("UpdateCD", "UpdateView")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    tableOutput("viewCD")
                  )
               )
      )
      )
```

Here goes the server piece of the code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
       filedatafx <- reactiveFileReader(10000, session, "fx.csv", read.csv)
       filedatacd <- reactiveFileReader(10000, session, "cd.csv", read.csv)
       output$StFX = renderUI({
              mydata = filedatafx()
              choices = mydata$col1 #Fetching choices from a column of the data
              choices = unique(choices)
              selectInput('dropdownFX', 'Types', choices)
              })

       output$StCD = renderUI({
              mydata = filedatacd()
              choices = mydata$col1 #Fetching choices from a column of the data
              choices = unique(choices)
              selectInput('dropdownCD', 'Types', choices)
              })

       datasetInputFX <- eventReactive(input$updateFX, {
              mydata = filedatafx()
              ListOfST <- by(mydata,mydata[,"col1"], function(x) x) #Grouping data based on values in Col1.
              data.df <- data.frame(ListOfST[input$dropdownFX]) #Show values for the selected value in the dropdown.
              colnames(data.df) <- c("ColA", "ColB", "DP","ColE", "ColF", "ColG","ColA", "ColX", "ColY","ColZ")
              data.df["DP"] <- NULL #Some preprocessing of the other columns before rendering.
              return(data.df)
              }. ignoreNULL = FALSE)

       datasetInputCD <- eventReactive(input$updateCD, {
              mydata = filedatacd()
              ListOfST <- by(mydata,mydata[,"col1"], function(x) x) #Grouping data based on values in Col1.
              data.df <- data.frame(ListOfST[input$dropdownCD]) #Show values for the selected value in the dropdown.
              #Changing column names
              colnames(data.df) <- c("ColA", "ColB", "DP","ColE", "ColF", "ColG","ColA", "ColX", "ColY","ColZ")
              data.df["DP"] <- NULL #Some preprocessing of the other columns before rendering.
              return(data.df)
              }. ignoreNULL = FALSE)

       output$viewFX <- renderTable({datasetInputFX(). include.rownames = FALSE})
       output$viewCD <- renderTable({datasetInputCD(). include.rownames = FALSE})
          }
```

On the first load it gives me this error:

> Error: 'names' attribute[10] must be the same length as the vector[0]

I think it is an error in the colnames piece of the code because it is of length 10. And something to do with how the reactive reader works. This error vanishes when I click **Update View** to update the table but always appear on the first load of the page. (i.e even when I click refresh on the browser)

Comment: I am not sure I'm even close with my suggestion, but could it be that you need to select a default value for the `output$StFX` and `output$StCD`? In `SelectInput()` you can provide a default value, perhaps this is the input that's missing for the code to run. As soon as you clicked `Update View`, this part of the code gets its first value..

Comment: But if you see the code, the choices possible in selectInput are data dependent. So can't supply a default value there.